# Paypal REST API: Displaying plans with both "created" and "active" statuses with Plan::all() method

Tags: php, rest, paypal, recurring-billing

I am working with the REST API and cannot figure out how to display all of my "created" and "active" billing plans. I am able to choose one or the other, and all of the necessary information is returned correctly. I have tried nested arrays, and specifying the same parameter, even trying an empty array for the parameters...I can't seem to figure out how to get it working though.

[Documentation for reference](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/#list-plans)

[PayPal Example for reference](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://raw.githubusercontent.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/master/sample/doc/billing/ListPlans.html)

Currently my code to list all active billing plans is as follows.

```
try {
    $params = ['status' => 'created'];
    $all_plans = Plan::all($params, $this->apiContext);
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    ResultPrinter::printError("List of Plans", "Plan", null, $params, $ex);
    exit(1);
}
```

Is it possible to do something like `['status' => ['active','created']]`, or a similar technique to grab both status types? Currently I am addressing this with a method to get the active plans, another to get the created plans, and then merging them together...I would prefer not to do this though as this project should only have 2-3 plans at a time.

Thanks.